# Primary Key issues when using raw_input with SQLite 3 and Python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

in my database I'm using `raw_input` to allow users to enter data into a database, the problem is that I have an ID assigned to each record of data that is the primary key of the table.

```
username = raw_input("What would you like your username to be? ")
email = raw_input("What is your email address? ")
firstName = raw_input("What is your first name? ")
surname = raw_input("What is your surname? ")
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
password = raw_input("What is your password?") #Encryption method will be added later
age = int(age) #Changing the age variable into an integer so it can be inputted into the database

#DB part
conn = db.connect('apollo.db') #Connecting to the database
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (username, email, firstName, surname, age, password)) #Inserting the user's data into the table

conn.commit() #Committing the changes

conn.close() #Closing the connection
```

I assumed that because the primary key increments automatically that it would not be needed to be added into the code because each record would automatically get a number. The problem is, I get this error message when I've answered all of the `raw_input` questions:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table users has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
```

Is there something I need to add to the code for the primary key?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is this:

<strike>`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",`</strike>

Try this exchange of that:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, email, firstName, surname, age, password) VALUES ",
        (username, email, firstName, surname, age, password))
```

and i think this **[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm)** can explain it more for you my friend.

Comment: I would add that you either provide all columns in the order the table defined them, or you explicitly list the column names, in any order you want, inside parenthesis after the table name. On an insert though, this assumes the missing columns have a default value.

Comment: Btw, Hamidreza guessed the column names from your variable names, but of course your columns might have different names ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments my friend ,honestly i just guess the names.